# When a page is resized, how does it beautifully and orderly reposition itself?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For example, www.breakingnews.com is using Twitter Bootstrap, which does a great job at this sort of repositioning.  When the browser window is resized horizontally, the page adjusts accordingly.  Column sizes shrink, columns and headers disappear, icons and buttons shift aside, and text is realigned. How does this work?

Comment: when you say minimized do you mean resized?

Comment: That's correct. My fault on the incorrect wording. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case CSS media queries are being used. This allows for different stylesheets to be used depending on the width of the device. This means they have a small, medium and large stylesheet which shows different columns depending on the width. [This tutorial covers media queries.](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

In addition to this the widths of elements must be specified in %. This is called a fluid layout. This makes them relevant to the current browser size. A fixed width layout is the same width regardless of the browser size and thus simply cuts off content when the browser is resized.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  They are using CSS3 and @meda screen and (max-wdith: x) to set the values.

So, they have code like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #identity { 
    margin-left:6.15%;
  }
}
```

Inside their all.css file.

Answer (score 2):

This is a technique generally called "[Responsive Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design)", that's both a (pretty simple) technical implementation and a way of designing for variable screen sizes. The linked book is a short and straightforward description, or read about it pretty much everywhere.